# How to get screen shot using php

Tags: php

I have install `boxcutter-1.5` in my project I am running below given command nothing is happening. How should I fix this.

```
$exec = exec('boxcutter -f image.png');
```

Comment: You can receive the output result of the [exec function](http://www.php.net/function.exec) by passing an optional second parameter. So check second parameter value for check if there is any error?

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php This may help you.

Comment: Hope you are using this setup into Win. As per [GIT version](https://github.com/mdrasmus/boxcutter), _boxcutter-fs is a minimal Windows command line screenshot application_

Comment: I need to genrate screenshot using php and save it in folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919550/capture-image-with-imagegrabscreen-and-wamp

Comment: what happens when you run 'boxcutter -f image.png' from the command line?

Comment: I am getting a screen shot on cmd prompt, but how to same run in PHP.